# Is "potential" a countable noun?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Is "potential" a countable noun? Consider these sentences:

> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potentials?
>
> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's levels of potential?
>
> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potentials?

Comment: "Potential" may occur as a plural (for some) , but that doesn't mean it's a count noun. It's a non-count noun since it cannot combine with the cardinal numbers "one, two, three" etc. There's no *"two/three/potentials".

Comment: @Barmar, the question shouldn't have been edited as it made total sense and the nature of what is been asked has changed. The question wasn't whether the 3 questions were correct or not; furthermore the first and last question are the same.

Comment: @aesking I couldn't make sense of the question as originally written, unless he was asking which is more correct. And the duplication was in the original.

Comment: It's countable in the same sense that "measurement" is countable.

Comment: @HotLicks this question is a bit more complicated, if you have a group of people you take their measurement**s** (each group member has their own measurement, perhaps even multiple measurements depending on context), whereas in this case you could also speak of the **potential** the audience has as whole (as opposed to each audience member's individual potential).

Comment: @JJJ -- And you could say the same thing about the *measurement* of the audience's weight.

Comment: Again is the OP asking if 'potential' or 'potentials' is a count noun or not? LOL. Because I was under the impression we were talking about the noun 'potential' and not its plural form.

Comment: My question is: Countable nouns have a singular and plural form. Is it really a countable noun when its only a countable noun in its plural form?

Comment: Speaking of counts, what is the difference between the 1st and 3rd example lines???

Comment: @aesking the only problem is that the Oxford dictionary disagrees with us .. so, maybe I should delete the comment.  They seem to see such thing as "a potential"  ..  I suppose a "likelihood for fame" and a "likelihood for fortune" are two "likelihoods" ... or a "knack for knitting" and a "knack for puzzles" as 'two knacks"  ..  I guess if you can have a "x for" it is a thing - certainly  we have "the loves of my life in common use.  I am deleting, reluctantly.

Comment: @Tom22 Edwin disagrees with ODO too. Don't you think its strange there is no plural form of potential in the context we are talking about (because it can't be counted) and perhaps why 'he has potential (maybe more than one potential)' is idiomatic. Yes in science it can be counted and hence it has both singular and plural forms: 1 action potential; 2 action potentials (it can be counted and has both plural forms-hence why it is a count noun) but not when referring to a person's potential ("uncountable nouns don't have a plural"-only singular). It makes sense does it not?

Comment: e.g. Definition of potential: latent **qualities or abilities** that may be developed and lead to future success or usefulness.
"a young broadcaster with great potential"

Comment: also can technology have more than 1 potentials because it is non-human just like action potentials are? or abstract ideas. it is not talking a **person's** potential, which is different?

Comment: @aesking while I still believe there are issues and that use in particular is strained, it is hard to say.  Certainly if we were to say "his probabilities" it would be odd, but "his propensities" or 'the audience members' propensities' it would be ok.  I suppose the question is does "potential" refer to a personal quality or more like 'momentum' which refers to the growth in a task itself, not the person's degree of being naturally prone.  Is it "they have a potential as an actor, or they have potential in acting  (with or without the 'a' ) ... I think they are both used.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in **some cases** it is countable, example from [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potential):

> [count noun] ‘the potentials of the technology were never wholly controllable’

Also as a quantity (for example in physics or maths) it can be countable, example from [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potential):

> ‘Electrical action potentials, osmotic perturbations or chemical signals may trigger these waves.’

In mathematics (or science in general) you could say **scalar potentials** to refer to more than one **scalar potential**. An example of this can be found [here (lecture notes from the School of Physics and Astronomy of the University of Edinburgh)](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~rhorsley/SII08-09_mp2a/lec22_2.pdf).

Attribution: "Potential | Definition of Potential in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 03, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potential.

In **your case**, however, I would refer to this example from [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potential) and recommend the singular version in your sentence because you refer to the potential of the audience as a whole:

> ‘You could say that we can compare our capabilities and potential to that of an iceberg!’

So in your sentence that would be (without the **s**):

> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potential

Comment: How can it be in some cases? In the cases where it is not a countable noun, how is that possible? "Uncountable nouns have no plural". Therefore, couldn't it be argued that 'potentials' is a different word in meaning altogether?

Comment: @aesking **potential** is one word with different meanings, with some meanings it's countable, some it's not. In this case you could even argue it depends on what you mean: the potential of the audience as a whole (1) or the potential of all the individual audience members individually (2).

Comment: I'm going to disagree with ODO here. While I agree that the physics usage is count (eg 'Significance of two potentials for predicting successful catheter ablation from the left sinus of Valsalva for left ventricular epicardial tachycardia.' {[NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15305952)}, the first usage mentioned here is non-count as 'two / 316 / several potentials of the technology were never wholly controllable' is not acceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fair point, I replaced it with a better example.

Comment: @aesking As discussed in many previous threads, many nouns have both count and non-count usages (and what is considered acceptable keeps on changing). It is at best very risky to speak of 'non-count nouns'.

Comment: I still believe the ODO labelling of  ‘the potentials of the technology were never wholly controllable’ as showing a count usage is improper. Count usages accept numerals.

Comment: But if "potential" refers to the audience as a whole, shouldn't "capability" as well.  How can you claim one should be plural and the other singular"?

Comment: @HotLicks you can speak of capabilities with a singular subject. For example, you have many capabilities, when you were younger you had the potential to develop those capabilities.

Comment: @JJJ - So why do you say that there can be only one potential?  What's the difference?  A potential is just an unrealized capability.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it could depend on context, but I think in most cases the singular is more idiomatic, take for example: _You have potential. / You have the potential to ... / We will use your potential_. I think in those sentences the singular _potential_ can refer to multiple things (and I don't think you should write the plural in those cases).

Comment: @JJJ - I didn't say that the plural should be frequently used.  I just said it's not wrong to use it, in the appropriate case.  Consider  "You have the potential to ..." followed by "but you don't have the potential to do ..." -- two different potentials discussed.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure if that is idiomatic, I Googled "two potentials" but it shows almost exclusively science related results on the first couple of pages (those results might be tailored to me personally). If you aren't sure either but you want to know, I think it's best if you ask a new question specifically about potential used in the way you do now and if that is an idiomatic use of the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Potential cannot be counted at all, nor can it be measured specifically. Thus 'the teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potentials?' is correct.

Comment: It does not compute!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Sweeping statements should be backed up with suitable examples or references, and in fact, almost every non-count noun can be used in a countable way in some contexts. Consider, for instance, a business setting where *potential* might refer to prospective clients or customers; it would be quite ordinary to have a weekly meeting *to discuss the potentials in the pipeline* or some such.

Comment: So if shown a electrical circuit, an engineer cannot measure the *potentials* between points A & B, C & D, et al?  And there can't be more than one of those things, regardless of how many measuring points there are in the circuit?

Comment: @Hotlicks me and Annie were referring to the context of the question asked. you are talking about a different type of potential than we are.

Comment: @aesking - That 35-year old person there has the potential to become president, but, standing 4 feet tall, he does not have to potential to become the world's tallest person.  Two different potentials for one person.

Comment: @Hot licks so, did I say you can only have 1 potential?

Comment: Annie said "Potential cannot be counted at all".  I still have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @hotlicks We were trying to say you can't measure a person's potential as this is subjective. You can't physically measure a person's potential can you? Yes you can to a degree, but everyone self-actualises (Maslow's hierarchy of needs in Psychology) differently and therefore everyone's potential is different, so how can it be measured fairly? Thats why I used 'physically measure' as it can be measured on a scale, with categories etc. but whether it is ACTUALLY measuring potential can be questioned.

Comment: @aesking - How is an IQ test "subjective"?  How is a physical endurance test "subjective"?  And aren't school grades frequently used as a measure of "potential"?  Yes, "potential" is most often (in the non-scientific sense) used to refer to a subjective assessment, but that's not a hard-and-fast part of its definition.

Comment: @hot licks an IQ test is subjective though, isn't not? Are you gonna accept it as the truth because it is what it claims to be because it is refuted by 'scientific', systematic evidence? Psychology is pseudo-science and even then its still subjective. Psychiatry, which is based on science is subjective as no real cause and effect are being established in mental illness in drug treatments. Who says your potential is determined by your IQ or physical endurance? IMO. And yes but we don't know what exactly potential means here so how are you making the assumption the potential means school grades?

Comment: @aesking - I didn't say it's an accurate measure of potential, or widely applicable, but someone with an IQ of 70 has very little likelihood of ever winning the Nobel Prize in Physics.  However, that person may have amazing artistic talents -- a different outcome with a different potential.  (You seem to be hung up on the idea that an individual has only one potential, vs a vast multitude of them.)

Comment: @Hot licks Im not hung up one whether an individual has only 1 potential actually, I'm talking about whether POTENTIAL can actually be truly measured. Again the OP didn't state what he meant by potential as like you said, it can mean anything.

Comment: @aesking - It depends on the nature of the potential and the technique used to measure it, don't you think?  Have you never hears someone say "He has the potential to ..."?

Comment: @hotlicks Yes I do? Isn't that what I have said all along? Like did you read my answer below. Its subjective and you say 'it depends on the nature of the potential'. Yes I know what it means and I have said it depends on what the OP means by this. This is also the reason why there is no proper plural form of potential in the context we are talking about and perhaps why 'he has potential (maybe more than one potential)' is idiomatic. Yes in science it can be counted (action potentials-hence why it is a count noun) but not in the way we are talking about. It makes sense does it not?

Answer (score 0):

The original sample line (or at least 2 out of 3):

> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potentials

The question appears to hinge on whether this would better stated as:

> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's potential

These mean two different things.

In the first case the implication is that the "teachings" are "personalized" for each audience member, based on his/her "potential".

In the second case the implication is that the "teachings" will be somehow adjusted based on an overall analysis of the "potential" of the audience as a whole.

Looking at the other sample line:

> The teachings are dispensed according to the audience's levels of
>   potential?

This is just a slightly more awkward to say "... audience's potentials".

Answer (score -1):

A countable noun has to be measurable. The noun 'potential' cannot be physically measured as tables and chairs can, nor does it have a quantity - regardless of the words placed before it or the context. If 5 people in audience have potential, then the countable noun isn't potential but 'people'.

It suits the definition of an abstract noun more, as potential is a subjective thing-in terms of definition and qualifying characteristics of what it means to have potential.

Comment: So is "measurement" countable??

Comment: *Idea* is countable. How do you customarily measure the physical dimensions of an idea?

Comment: @choster. Easy. If a person has 5 ideas then you count how many ideas they have. You don't measure the physical dimension but the number of. That makes it physically measurable, I'd say.

Comment: @aesking You open your answer by stating a "a countable noun has to be physically measurable," however. Moreover, almost every non-count noun can be used in a count sense, for example, when discussion portions, examples, or varieties of something— hence *wines*, *joys*, *infinities*, etc.

Comment: @Choster  "almost every non-count noun can be used in a count sense." I thought we were talking about the word 'potenital' and not its plural form and what it could be. Therefore the noun 'potential' isn't a count noun like wines, joys and infinities. Countable nouns have a singular and plural form. Is it really a countable noun when its only a countable noun in its plural form?

Comment: @aesking I can select *a wine*, I can savor *a joy*, I can live *an infinity*. My point is that an audience can have potential, potentials, or a potential within contexts that you seem not to have considered.

Comment: Also I was using the context giving in the question, not irrelevant contexts.

Comment: @aesking - You're making absolutely no sense.  You can have multiple potentials -- sports potential, math potential, etc.  Potentials can (to a degree) be measured or assessed -- IQ test, sports tryout, etc.  You seem to be hung up on one narrow meaning for "potential".

Comment: @HotLicks I am aware that potential has different meanings, hence why I said its subjective. Do you have nothing to add rather than comment randomly at people's answers? What narrow meaning of potential did I state? "as potential is a subjective thing-in terms of definition and qualifying characteristics of what it means to have potential."

Comment: @HotLicks you seem to confuse context with meaning. the context is the audience. Other contexts could be, such as the use of potential in science. Action potentials ect.

Comment: @aesking - "Context" refers to the actual text in which the words are used.  There are wordings where singular is most appropriate, and wordings where plural is better.

Comment: No, context is background information. In the question the context is the audience as it is referring to the audience (situation), not action potentials in science (other contexts). Yes the word 'audience' can be subjective but my point was, my answer was more closely related to what the OP has provided and actually asked.